How to create a PDF using react-pdf/renderer in Express.js
I am trying to generate a PDF using some JSON data I will get from a source. Now I want to run this library in my Express.js application. However, I am running into errors related to babel and many more since I am having a hard time understanding the documentation.
This is my contents of index.js:


import express from "express";
import React from "react";
import ReactPDF from "@react-pdf/renderer";
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`The sample PDF app is running on port ${port}.`);
});
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const pdfStream = await ReactPDF.renderToStream(<MyDocument />);
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
  pdfStream.pipe(res);
  pdfStream.on("end", () => console.log("Done streaming, response sent."));
});



I want to render this specific document so I have kept it in MyDocument.jsx


const MyDocument = () => (
    <Document>
      <Page>
        <Text>React-pdf</Text>
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );
  
  await renderToFile(<MyDocument />, `${__dirname}/my-doc.pdf`);



Here is my package.json


{
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^3.4.2",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.24.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.1"
  }
}



I am trying to run this code using the nodemon command, but I am facing a lot of errors regarding babel, and many more. One of the most common errors is


const pdfStream = await ReactPDF.renderToStream(<MyDocument />);
                                                  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:119:18)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:468:14)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:68:21)

Node.js v18.17.1



Am I doing something wrong?
